# MVC 2 model with IList<T> properties binding question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

I'm working on an MVC 2 project and I have a model that looks like this:

```
public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
public IList<Equipment> ShippedEquipmentList { get; set; }
```

and a view that has a button for adding a new piece of equipment. Clicking the button dynamically adds new textboxes to the view for specifying another piece of equipment. The partial view it renders looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<RmaMVC.Models.Entities.Equipment>" %>

<div class="editorRow">
        Item: <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItemID); %>
        Value: <% Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description); %>
</div>
```

My question is: how do I bind this data to the model? When the controller gets called the ShippedEquipmentList comes back as null.

**Edit: here is what I have so far.** My model looks like this:

```
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public IList<Equipment> ShippedEquipmentList { get; set; }

    FormInputs()
    {
        ShippedEquipmentList = new List<Equipment>();

        // adding a single blank piece of equipment so that the length isn't 0
        Equipment blank = new Equipment();
        ShippedEquipmentList.Add(blank);
    }
```

my main view is this:

```
  <% Html.BeginForm(); %>       
    <div id="items">
    </div>
    <%: Ajax.ActionLink("add new", "AddNewEquipment", new AjaxOptions {
                UpdateTargetId = "items", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter }) %>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

    <% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormInputs input)
    {
        return View(input);
    }

    public ActionResult AddNewEquipment()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/RMA/EditorTemplates/Equipment.ascx");
    }
```

the partial view that generates the text boxes for the equipment:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<RmaMVC.Models.Entities.Equipment>" %>

<p>

<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItemID) %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description) %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Quantity) %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SerialNumber) %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Comment: In that example he knows exactly how many items will be bound to the collection (or I'm guessing he does since he's hard coding the size right into the for loop). What I can't figure out is how to do that with a model that has multiple IList properties, as well as other non-dynamic properties.

Comment: Here what said in article: _Note that the index must be an unbroken sequence of integers starting at 0 and increasing by 1 for each element._ So it doesn't matter if you generate it dynamically or on the client side with the fixed number of entities. Just follow naming conventions

Comment: I'll give it a go. I'm still kind of confused how it's going to bind a new Equipment object to an empty IList<Equipment> though, because when the view is loaded the list is empty so I'm not sure how entering the for loop will work.

Comment: 1. Create editor for the your entity. 2. Try to generate couple controls for couple entities using `<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m[i]) %>`. 3. Check how naming is set and try to create dynamically all necessary controls.

Comment: I've updated the code above. I get how to use Html.EditorFor(m => m[i]) but my problem is that I can't figure out how to add a new Equipment object to the List<Equipment> object in my Model when the user clicks the "Add New" ajax link.

Comment: try to just generate necessary fields (which is included in your editor mode;) but with updating indexes in names. It should work.